# data "cases" in JS API

Tags: javascript, json, api

I want to display the data "cases" from my API however nothing seems to happen, do you have a suggestion

```
 window.onload = function() {
    getCovidStats();
}

function getCovidStats() {
    fetch('https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/Morocco')
    .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() })
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        let cas = data.Object.cases;

        document.getElementById('cas').innerHTML = cas.toLocaleString('en');


    })
    .catch(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    setTimeout(getCovidStats, 43200000) // update every 12 hours
}
```

it seems to me that the data.object.cases path is wrong
here a `console.log(data)` of my API

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get cases to use `data.cases`, the data is itself an object having property cases you can use it by dot notation or square bracket notation.

Your updated code would look like this,

```js
 window.onload = function() {
    getCovidStats();
}

function getCovidStats() {
    fetch('https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/Morocco')
    .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() })
    .then(function(data) {
        document.getElementById('cas').innerHTML = data.cases;
    })
    .catch(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    setTimeout(getCovidStats, 43200000) // update every 12 hours
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `let cas = data.Object.cases;`
do this:
`let cas = data.cases;`

**Final code:**

```
window.onload = function() {
    getCovidStats();
}

function getCovidStats() {
    fetch('https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/Morocco')
    .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() })
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        let cas = data.Object.cases;

        document.getElementById('cas').innerHTML = cas.toLocaleString('en');


    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("error",err);
    })
    setTimeout(getCovidStats, 43200000) // update every 12 hours
}
```

**Suggestion:**
You can add err parameter to the function and log it inside catch for debugging purposes

```
.catch(function(err) {
        console.log("error",err);
    })
```